# Envío Array por Ajax JavaSctipt

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, array

Estoy intentando enviar un array por petición XMLHttpRequest en JavaScript a un PHP para posteriormente hacer una consulta a una base de datos y devolver la respuesta de nuevo a al HTML.

El código de la petición en JS es:

```javascript
cont=document.getElementById("contenido");

      elarray=usuarios.join();
      console.log(elarray); //Me imprime un String con los usuarios 
      separados por comas

     var xhttp7=new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp7.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
    
    var respuesta7= JSON.parse(this.response);
      if(respuesta7!=""){

       for(i=0; i<respuesta7.length; i++){
    cont.innerHTML+="<tr><td><img style=width:200px; 
    src='fotos/"+respuesta7[i].foto+"'></td><br><td><span 
    style='background-color: brown'>"+respuesta7[i].nombre+" 
    <span></td><td>"+respuesta7[i].apellido+"</td></tr>";
       }      
      }

      else{
    alert("Error al cargar los usuarios");
      } 
    }

  };
  

  xhttp7.open("GET", "favoritosEnvio.php?usuarios="+elarray,false);
  xhttp7.send();
```

Sin embargo, a la hora de recibir la respuesta de la petición, me llega solo el último elemento del array.
El PHP al que envío los datos es:

```
   $totalFavs=$_GET['totalFavs'];

   $totalFavs=explode( ',', $totalFavs); //Convierto la cadena a array de 
                                           nuevo

     for($i=0; $i<count($elarray); $i++){ 

           $totalusuarios= mysqli_query($conexion,"select * from users where 
           nombre='$elarray[$i]'");

              if($totalusuarios){

                if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("<p>Conexión fallida: %s</p>", 
                 mysqli_connect_error());
                 exit();
                }

           $registros = mysqli_num_rows($totalusuarios);
            ?>


         
          $array=array();

          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($totalusuarios)){ 
           array_push($array,array(
           "foto"=>$row["foto"],
           "nombre"=>$row["nombre"],
            "apellido"=>$row["apellido"]
           )); 
        }


      }
   }

   $json=json_encode($array);
   $objeto=json_decode($json);
   echo($json);
```

¿Cómo podría realizarlo correctamente? Ya que realizo el bucle FOR en el PHP pero por alguna manera no se está realizando y me devuelve solo los datos del último elemento del array. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Lo primero que veo es que en esta línea, tienes un error de escritura:
xhttp7.open("GET", "favoritosEnvio.php?wlarray="+elarray. 
wlarray

Comment: Cierto, gracias, ya lo he editado. @H.Díaz

Comment: Pero `json_encode` es esa función de PHP, porque la tienes dentro del código javascript? Debes usar `JSON.stringify(total)`

Comment: la teoria dice que http usa parametros por get en forma de texto plano, por ende, debes mandar el arra transformado en texto plano, separado por comas u otro caracter y luego en php transformas con explode

Comment: Hola, gracias por la contestación! @John, he editado la pregunta con las modificaciones pero me sigue dando el error, qué puede ser?

Comment: Creo que el error está en `var respuesta7= JSON.stringify(this.response);`, porque estás recibiendo una cadena que debes interpretar (parse) en vez de convertir nuevamente en cadena (stringify). Entonces, debería ser `var respuesta7= JSON.parse(this.response);` para que convierta la cadena en un objeto (o arreglo de objetos).

Comment: revisa tu consola y si puedes danos mas detalles con captura de [pantalla F12](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqidDznZdIY)

Comment: @John He cambiado parte del código como puedes ver en la pregunta, y ahora sí me pinta los datos pero sólo del último elemento del array.

Comment: No entiendo, cuando haces esto `xhttp7.onreadystatechange=function()` estás seteando un nombre para instanciar a tu función más adelante. Estando de esta forma te debería saltar error.

Comment: @paskpinfo estas reescribiendo $array=array();  siempre, tienes que hacer un arreglo de 2 dimenciones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es muy mala idea ejecutar una consulta para cada usuario recibido. Puedes obtener todos usando [IN()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in):

```
$totalFavs = $_GET['totalFavs'];
$nombres = explode(',', $totalFavs);
// Con implode se encierran todos los valores entre comillas simples
// y se separan por comas para crear la cadena apropiada
$usuarios = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
       nombre IN ('" . implode("', '", $nombres) . "')";
if(!$usuarios){
    printf("<p>Error en consulta: %s</p>", 
    mysqli_error($conexion));
    exit();
}
// No es necesario contar registros
// Solo crea el arreglo
$array = [];
// Recorre los resultados
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($usuarios)){
    // Agrega cada usuario al arreglo
    $array[] = [
        "foto" => $row["foto"],
        "nombre" => $row["nombre"],
        "apellido" => $row["apellido"]
    ];
}
// Convierte a formato JSON
$json=json_encode($array);
// Envía como respuesta
echo($json);
```

**Importante:** Tu script es vulnerable a ataques SQL, deberías hacer validación de los datos recibidos y migrar a [sentencias preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).